# Cannot convert value of type CGSize to expected argument type NSCoder

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am getting a couple of errors like this in a few of my programs and been trying to fix it. Example: When I put size instead of coder it will tell me its incorrect and change it back to coder.

```
 func reset() {
            self.removeAllChildren()
        var viewSize = view?.bounds.size
        backgrounMusicPlayer.stop()
        replayButton.isHidden = true
        let gameScene = GameScene(coder: viewSize) //where error is 
        let transition = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
        gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
        self.scene!.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
    }
```

Comment: Why are you passing the ViewSize to the GameScene object? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The error is quite clear.

Comment: I am assuming you are trying to do `GameScene(size: viewSize)` and XCode yells at you to make it `GameScene(coder: viewSize)`?

Comment: Did you somehow change `GameScene` to not be a subclass `SKScene` anymore?

Comment: I would try doing total clean `CMD+ALT+SHIFT+K`, there could be some bad linking going on and XCode "forgot" that size exists as an available init

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your initialization of the `GameScene` object ... as the error implies.

```
let gameScene = GameScene(coder: viewSize) //where error is
```

You are passing in a CGSize object, when this initializer expects an NSCoder object. I'm assuming that `GameScene` is a subclass of `SKScene`, you should be initializing with

```
let gameScene = GameScene(size: viewSize)
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid to write wrong syntax you could use the **XCode** autocompletion.
**Control + SpaceBar** triggers XCode’s autocomplete functionality, also when you want to know the available init methods about a generic class like [SKScene](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene) you simply write:

[image]

Doing this **you can immediatly see input properties and the required types**.

About your case you have a class named **GameScene** that subclass `SKScene` and you try to make:

```
SKScene.init(coder: <#T##NSCoder#>)
```

Obviusly you cannot pass `viewSize` as the input parameter for this init method. You should use `init(size: CGSize)` method

---

**Details**:

Now we speak about the `init(coder: NSCoder)`. 
The procedure to save the state of your view to disk is known as serialization. The reverse is deserialization - restoring the state of the object from disk.

```
override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    // Serialize your object here
}

override init() {
    super.init()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // Deserialize your object here
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

These methods are needed in your custom class to speak with Interface Builder, for example objects to the storyboard,  that serialize  the state of that object on to disk and deserialize it when you use the storyboard but if you don't add any new properties to your subclass you can also avoid to write your own serialization and deserialization code for the subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `GameScene` class is a subclass of `SKScene`, it doesn't have an initializer with a `coder` label.

Just change `GameScene(coder: viewSize)` to `GameScene(size: viewSize)`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a SpriteKit Project, the GameScene class does not need the size and only requires the name of the .sks file which represent the scene. (the size would be set as property on that file)
 Try this, it would reset and represent the game scene again

```
  if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GAME_SCENE_FILE_NAME") {
      scene.replayButton.isHidden = true
      let transition = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
      scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
      self.view!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this line in my GameViewController.swift.  It was trying to make me "correct" my code to use "coder" instead of "size" and NScoder was the type.:

```
let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
```

I commented out this part of my code in my GameScene.Swift.  That fixed my problem.

```
/*
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //        theSelf = self

        //        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder) //VL:4/1/2015 had to comment out for some reason
    }
*/
```

Intuition helped me figure it out.  I did a search for NSCoder in my project and found this.  Which essentially was changing how the GameScene inits.   This project started at least as far back as xcode 6, which is probably why.